# Flutter - NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null - though null handling condition

Tags: firebase, flutter

Here's my code, I keep getting the error: ***NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null*** ,even though I am handling the null case

[image]

Comment: Please [avoid uploading code as picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Why do you need `as dynamic` here? Besides your code is not checking null value, only returns the progress indicator in case the connection state is waiting. You can check for null data with `snapshot.hasData`.

Comment: My bad, I edited the question with the right image. Still not working with snapshot.hasData

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check what's in `snapshot.data`. It is also a good practice to check for errors with `snapshot.hasError`.

Comment: Given my code, how would you advise me to do so?

Comment: Did you add the breakpoint? Examine whats in the snapshot at different times. Let the code jump and stop more times because the value of snapshot will be different.